# Formula for diplomacy in Civ 5?

Tags: civilization-5

Since the AI in Civilization 5 are, as their name suggests, artificial, that means that all their actions are determined by numbers and formulas.

That would include the diplomacy between the AI and the player.

So what is the formula that determines the AI's view of the player?

For instance, I found [this thread](http://forums.civfanatics.com/showthread.php?t=431839) on the Civilization fanatics forum that details how the "warmonger" part of diplomacy is factored.

It says that the warmonger score with another civilization is caluclated by: (other civilization's warmonger hate factor) * (5 * (declarations of war against major civilizations) + 10 * (major civilizations conquered) + 5 * (declarations of war against minor civilizations) + 10 * (minor civilizations conquered))
This score then corresponds to several levels, 200 + is critical, 150-200 is severe, 100-150 is major, 50-100 is minor, and less than 50 is none. Critical then corresponds to -100 diplo points with that civilization, severe is -70, major is -40, and minor is -15.

To put that in comparison a declaration of friendship gives +35 diplo points.

So what other formulas can be taken from the XML files to determine the overall diplomatic calculation?

Comment: I found the document that contains all the diplomatic weights for every action that the AI consider, you can find it at C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\sid meier's civilization v\assets\Gameplay\XML\AI\GlobalDiplomacyAIDefines.xml

For example, if you are taking wonders they want you run the risk of getting the OPINION_WEIGHT_WONDER_FIERCE tag which damages relations by 20 points, if you then go down in the document you see that WONDER_DISPUTE_FIERCE_THRESHOLD is 10, I can't find any other things in the document other than that, so I can only assume that it means 10 wonders

Comment: So if you have built 10 wonders that the AI wanted (even if they were no where near getting them) then you will take 20 diplomatic point hits. I am unsure how the AI determine what wonders they want, but if they're a civ like Egypt and you have 10 wonders, you can almost guarantee that you will be taking 20 diplomatic point hits.

Comment: you get hints here and there - Civs that proposes one sided Open Borders, and refuses when you want a both sided Open Border, are very much likely going to compete with you for high culture / high tourism wonders. You can also expect warmongering civs to want stuff like Brandenburg gate.

Answer (score 1):

Civ V , like any game, has an (in this case quite large) element of randomness. At the start of each game (and every time you load a save if the specific option is selected when you set up a game), a pseudorandom seed is generated, which determines many actions in game.
This is easily shown by early game combat scenarios, ie. problems with barbarians in my games as Brazil. Sometimes I can destroy a barbarian encampment with one Archer, and sometimes I need another unit. Diplomacy is also governed by this random seed. Although each AI civ has a specific personality, their actions are also determined by the seed.

Answer (score -2):

Unfortunately there is no official formula but if you have enough gold and luxury items such as marble and dyes etc. they will happily all become your ally. At least that is how I have managed in my games